# Docker container runs locally but fails on Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run, python-poetry

I moved project from PIP to Poetry and my Docker container failed to run on Google Cloud Run.

Last string in Docker:

```
CMD ["poetry", "run", "uwsgi", "--http-socket", "0.0.0.0:80", "--wsgi-file", "/server/app/main.py", "--callable", "app", "-b 65535"]
```

It's works locally, it's works on other laptop, it's works in Cloud Run Emulator, but fails when I try to run it on Cloud Run.

Here is a Cloud Run log:

```
Creating virtualenv my-project-xTUGyw3C-py3.8 in /home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs

FileNotFoundError

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'/bin/uwsgi'

at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py:601 in _execvpe
597│ path_list = map(fsencode, path_list)
598│ for dir in path_list:
599│ fullname = path.join(dir, file)
600│ try:
→ 601│ exec_func(fullname, *argrest)
602│ except (FileNotFoundError, NotADirectoryError) as e:
603│ last_exc = e
604│ except OSError as e:
605│ last_exc = e
Container called exit(1).
```

It's have correct port set. It's doesn't use any environment variables. I don't use volumes, files passed to Docker through COPY.

Logs says that application can't find uwsgi file. That file doesn't exists in local version too, but it's works without any errors.

How that even possible that a docker container behaves differently?

UPD: My Docker file

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR server
ENV PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH:/server
RUN pip install poetry==1.1.11
COPY poetry.lock /server
COPY pyproject.toml /server
RUN poetry install
EXPOSE 80
COPY /data /server/data
COPY /test /server/test
COPY /app /server/app
CMD ["poetry", "run", "uwsgi", "--http-socket", "0.0.0.0:80", "--wsgi-file", "/server/app/main.py", "--callable", "app", "-b 65535"]
```

Comment: Are you creating a virtualenv inside your container? As well, `uwsgi` is defined in the `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Probably would be helpful to post your Dockerfile. And make sure there's no credentials in there...

Comment: The error is **No such file or directory: b'/bin/uwsgi'**. Edit your question and include the  build/deploy commands and the Dockerfile. Show how you are setting up the WSGI server.

Comment: I think the OP is correct to question why a container would run one place but not on Cloud Run. There are, of course, differences:.the Linux kernel and/or implementation (shim) to the Linux syscallsl, the container runtime etc. I wonder whether the Cloud Run runtime is being overly restrictive (or erroneous). The error is in Python's os,py ([link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ba5725171d9c411fc4764349205eff5cfc028797/Lib/os.py#L606)) and the code looks to be looping through the path trying to find the uwsgi binary. For some reason, the behavior differs on Cloud Run.

Comment: It's unclear to me whether there's debugging significance between running a container using Docker on a host and running it under Cloud Run Emulator on the same host. Doesn't Minikube share the Docker Engine in such a config? Or does it run its own?

Comment: @DazWilkin - the answer is in details that are not present in the question. At this point, we can only guess.

Comment: Added Dockerfile

Comment: The default port for Cloud Run is port 8080 and not port 80. You also did not include your build and deploy commands.

Comment: It's doesn't matter because I set port 80 in Cloud Run. I build with standart docker build . -t <image-tag> then push it to gcr.io and paste link to image in cloud run

Comment: Idk why but if I install everything using pip instead of poetry, everything works fine

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. have you found a solution?

Comment: Please, can you share your `pyproject.toml` file?

Answer (score 3):

adding `HOME=/root` to the CMD, fixed the problem for me.

```
CMD HOME=/root poetry run python main.py
```

Apparently home is not set correctly and this is a [known issue](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#home)