# Building docker image fails on Google cloud build but works locally

Tags: docker, go, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, gqlgen

I have Golang project which I am trying to deploy to Google Cloud Run. For this project the idea is to test image building and running before even deploying it to cloud run. Now building this image **locally** and on **Github action** works really well without any problem.

But when push source code to Google Cloud Run the deployment fails. On Cloud Build history I get the following error

```
Removing intermediate container d76fa08a24bd
 ---> 264891a391d2
Step 7/10 : RUN go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen generate
 ---> Running in 7282b9df5a6c
unable to open schema: open schema.graphql: no such file or directory
exit status 1
The command '/bin/sh -c go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen generate' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

But `ls -R` shows that the file is there and I wonder why building image works locally and on Gihub action but not on Cloud build. Is there something I am missing? Of course I don't have any `cloudbuild.yaml`

Here is my Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM golang:1.20-alpine

WORKDIR /app

# Copy only the go mod and sum files to leverage Docker cache
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Download dependencies
RUN go mod download

# Copy the rest of the application
COPY . ./

#RUN ls -R #for showing if everything is copied correclty.

# Generate code. ===HERE IS WHERE IT FAILS ON CLOUD BUILD===
RUN go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen generate

# Build the application
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o /wonder

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "/wonder" ]
```

And here is my github action.

```yaml
name: Docker Build Test

on:
  #workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
env:
  PROJECT_ID: my-project 
  SERVICE: wonder 
  REGION: europe-west1 

jobs:
  build:
    name: Test Docker Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      contents: 'read'
      id-token: 'write'

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: 'actions/checkout@v4'

      - id: 'auth'
        name: 'Authenticate to GCP'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
        with:
          create_credentials_file: 'true'
          workload_identity_provider: 'projects/987654321/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/action-pool/providers/action-oidc'
          service_account: 'wonder-g-diployer@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

      - name: Test Docker build
        working-directory: ./server
        run: |
          docker-compose up -d
          docker build -t wonder .
          docker run -d \
            -e "DB_HOST=localhost" \
            -e "DB_PORT=5434" \
            -e "DB_NAME=wonder" \
            -e "DB_PASSWORD=password" \
            --net=host \
            wonder

      - name: Check if server is running
        run: |
          sleep 10 # Wait for the server to start (you can adjust this if needed)
          if curl -sSf "http://localhost:8080/status" > /dev/null; then
            echo "Server is running."
            exit 0
          else
            echo "Server is not running or endpoint is not accessible."
            exit 1
          fi
      
      - name: Deploy to Cloud Run
        id: deploy
        uses: 'google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v2'
        with:
          service: ${{ env.SERVICE }}
          region: ${{ env.REGION }}
          source: ./server/

      # If required, use the Cloud Run url output in later steps
      - name: Show Output
        run: echo ${{ steps.deploy.outputs.url }}
```

Comment: Have a look at this [thread1](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/issues/560) & [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71083833/docker-container-runs-locally-but-fails-on-cloud-run) which might help

Comment: @SathiAiswarya I have taken a look, but don;t know what to modify excalty. I just tried ```RUN HOME=/root go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen generate``` but problem is strill there

Comment: Try `go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen init` instead? 

Example from: https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen

Comment: "open schema.graphql: no such file or directory" did that file get committed?

Comment: @erik258 it is there. I get proof with RUN ls -R

Answer (score 0):

You want to `genreate` from `.graphql` file with this package `github.com/99designs/gqlgen` and this package want to open your `schema.graphql` file and it is not found and can't open.

- Check where is you `schema.graphql` file?
- `github.com/99designs/gqlgen` read how to use this package for generating `.graphql` files

If not helped

- uninstall and anew init this package `github.com/99designs/gqlgen`

Comment: Thanks for responding. Isn't strange that image is generated successfully via github action and locally using same source code and same Dockerfile? I think problem could be the environment

Comment: Yes it's true. Maybe try to deploy a small project with this particular package in another cloud? If you have time and access to another one. ))